# Why can't I spawn a simple command with node.js?

Tags: command-line, node.js

```
pipe(): Too many open files

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Error spawning
```

That's my error. My code is:

```
grep  = spawn 'ls'
```

**UPDATE**

for tweet in indexedTweetsResults
    exec 'ls', (error, stdout, stderr) ->
      console.log stdout

This is my code and it errors with the `pipe` error. Any ideas?

Comment: **Possible Duplicate**: [Why can't I spawn a simple command with node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036093/too-many-open-files-when-using-nodejs-child-processes-spawn-to-run-scripts)

Comment: wondering where you got that idea, it doesn't resemble any sample node code I've seen.  @hvgotcodes has the right answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu need to do

`exec = require("child_process").exec`

and then somewhere do

```
exec("ls", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
   // handle error, stdout, stderr
});
```

you have to write javascript....

Comment: Strange - I have this in a function that's called 2 functions in and it returns the error. If it's the only thing in the file, then it works fine