# exec 'npm init' programmatically with node child process, but could not know when it finished

Tags: node.js, child-process

I use `child_process.exec` to run `npm init`, I can let it create package.json, but after creating, my stdin seems still open, I want to know when my child process finished so I maybe close the stdin, but I could not know when it finished.

Here is my code:

```
var child = exec('npm init', function (err, stdout, stderr) {

    console.log('over');
});
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

    process.stdout.write(data);

    //process.stdin.resume();
});
child.stdout.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end out');
});
child.stdout.on('close', function() {
    console.log('close out');
});
child.on('exit', function() {
    console.log('exit');
});
child.on('close', function() {
    console.log('close');
});
child.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnect');
});

// read stdin and send to child process
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {

    var chunk = process.stdin.read();

    if(chunk !== null) {
        child.stdin.write(chunk);
    }
});
```

None of events fired after it finishing create package.json, so how to close it when it finished?

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same issue and finally solved it in a completely different way. But I would assume to use `spawn` instead of `exec`. Because in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js) it is assumes for I/O processes.

> If you need to use handle process I/O with streams, such as when you are expecting large amounts of output, use [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

If you still want to use `exec`, I have solved it by checking for the last question in `npm init` process, and then firing `process.exit(0)` after the chunk has been written. But this didn't made me happy, so I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('npm test', (err, stdout) => {
          console.log(stdout);
          console.log('over');
        });
```