# Running and storing output of Python app in Node.JS

Tags: node.js

I want to run a python code (from text area) and show it's output as a text (HTML) in Node.JS.

Is there any way for doing this?

So, I want to access an external app of server, run with parameter and store it's output in Node.JS.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback to learn how to run external processes and manipulate their output.

There are examples in this q&a: [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)