# Execute system command from javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was executing NodeJS files in terminal like, `node filename.js` but I need to execute this command from JavaScript/jQuery i.e. from html page itself. Is it possible? How?

Comment: You can't execute system commands in browser.

Comment: you may be able to achieve something with a browser extension, but then it's browser specific and good luck doing anything with internet exploder at all

Comment: The question is, why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: this is impossible because of security reasons. If you need to execute system commands, consider to write own standalone client.

Comment: I tried with batch files, and in button click(in HTML page) i am triggering that batch file, but the batch file is not getting executed, instead its content get displayed in new tab. I am using IOS X. Is it possible to make execute that batch file with a button click?

Comment: On the backend expose some API - than call it from frontend via AJAX / websockets

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am aware about it, javascript can not interact with client machine from browser, and it should not be able to do it for security reasons.

But you should be able to run system commands on server. The idea is that you make GET to some [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) resource which executes system commands on serverside.

I think this should be useful [execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

(I think that such approach exposes server and everything on it to a security risk. Access to the server must be heavily monitored!!!)