# Running CLI commands in Sails.js application

Tags: sails.js, command-line-interface

I need to run PostgreSQL script right after lifting my application. For example, I need to execute this command: `psql -d DOGHOUZ -a -f script.sql` from the app. Is there a way how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends how you lift your app. If you use:

```
node app.js
```

you can add

```
sails.on('lifted', function yourEventHandler () {
    console.log('lifted')
});
```

in your app.js file before line sails.lift(rc('sails'));

Otherwise you need to add that into configuration. Best approach would be creating new file in /config like /config/eventhooks.js with content:

```
module.exports.eventhooks = function(cb) {
    sails.on('lifted', function yourEventHandler () {
        console.log('lifted')
    });
}
```

You can read more here:

- [Sails Events](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/application/events)
- [Sails Lifecycle](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/application/lifecycle)
- [Events Usage](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/EVENTS.md#usage)

**Edit 1**

To execute CLI commands just do:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'psql -d DOGHOUZ -a -f script.sql';
exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr){
    // command output is in stdout
});
```

More about executing commands in CLI you can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Comment: The main emphasis of this question is how run CLI. I adjusted my origin question.