# How to get output from node exec when running `npm install`?

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I'm running the following:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
let installProcess = exec('npm install');
    installProcess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    installProcess.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

But I get no output in my terminal, what else can I try?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/20643568/2308005

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following ended up working for me:

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
execSync('npm install', {stdio:[0,1,2]});
```

Comment: Didn't you mean to write `const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;`?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const installProcess = exec('npm install --verbose');

installProcess.stdout.on('data', process.stdout.write);
installProcess.stderr.on('data', process.stdout.write);
installProcess.on('close', (code) => process.stdout.write(`exited with ${code}`));
```

and the result

```
❯ node index.js   
stderr: npm
stderr:  info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.3.0/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.3
npm info using node@v6.3.0

stderr: npm verb 
stderr: correctMkdir /Users/bwin/.npm/_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing

stderr: npm
stderr:  info lifecycle tmp@1.0.0~preinstall: tmp@1.0.0

stderr: npm verb
stderr:  exit [ 0, true ]

stderr: npm info 
stderr: ok 

exited with 0
```

Comment: This does not work for me, the only output i get is "exited with 0"