# Electron: securely delete a file from filesystem

Tags: node.js, windows, macos, cross-platform, electron

I need to do a secure file deletion within a cross platform electron app, trying to avoid [data remanence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_remanence) of those files, so a simple [fs.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback) is not enough.

The effect I'd like to achieve is similar to the unix [`shred` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_(Unix)).

I tried in a linux Environment where I could just invoke a `shred` with [a direct system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js), but I need it to work in a cross-platform environment (windows and osx in particular) and I didn't found any useful command or npm library.

Any suggestion on how this could be done?

Comment: I would over write the data myself.

Comment: This is what I want to get, but how would you implement it? (being sure you overwrite the original files)