# Executing shell/ssh commands via web app

Tags: python, node.js, bash, rest, ssh

I would like to run commands on my home server via a web app. Is there a way to do this?

I have no interest in returning the output, I just want to execute commands like irsend when a button is pressed on the page.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js

Comment: Yes, however it is giving me an error. 
My main.js which I ran through browserify:

const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('ls', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
});

This gives an error of exec is not a function

Comment: Edit you question with code as you trying and the follow error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute commands directly from the browser, that is why `child_process.exec()` does not work when browserify your code.

You will need to send an HTTP request of some kind to the server and have it run the command there instead (using `child_process.exec()`/`child_process.spawn()`).