# Is it possible to permanently set environment variables?

Tags: node.js

I need a way to set an environment variable permanently. I could get away with having this only work in Windows for now, but ideally i'd like a solution that is OS agnostic. From what I can tell though, Node will only set the var for the current process/children processes. Is what I want even possible?

Comment: "Permanently" as in affecting other shells and surviving a reboot? This is *extremely* platform specific, even to the point of depending on what shell the person is using. I don't know that there's a library that does this, nor that this is even a good idea as people have a right to be upset if you start jamming environment variables into their shell configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Can probably use [`setx`](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) and `export`, though not sure of implications/privileges required (I would assume in windows a UAC bump would be necessary, and in linux you'd need sudo). Here's a best-guess:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

// Add FOO to global environment with value BAR
//   setEnv('FOO', 'BAR', callback)
// Append /foo/bar to PATH
//   setEnv('PATH', '+=;/foo/bar', callback)
function setEnv(name, value, cb) {
  if (!name) throw new Error('name required.');
  if (typeof value === 'undefined') throw new Error('value required.');

  var cmd;
  if (value.indexOf('+=') === 0) value = process.env[name] + value.substring(2);
  value = value.indexOf(' ') > -1 ? `"${value}"` : value;

  switch (process.platform) {
    case 'linux': cmd = `export ${name}=${value}`; break;
    case 'win32': cmd = `setx ${name} ${value} /m"; break;
    default: throw new Error('unsupported platform.'); break;
  }

  exec(cmd, cb);
}
```

I should mention this really isn't ideal; I recommend defining them as part of your execution task or look at using something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: Why isn't this ideal?

Comment: I can't think of a *good* reason why I would modify a system-level environment value in the context of a node script. I mean *possibly* in an instance such as installing something from a generator, but I still wouldn't want a package modifying my env.

Answer (score 3):

Write a file named **setEnv.js** and paste the following code in that.

Save file somewhere in your system, eg. in `D:\Codes\JS`.

#### step 1

```
const {spawnSync} = require("child_process");

// setx  -m  MyDownloads  H:\temp\downloads
var result = spawnSync('setx', ['-m', 'MyDownloads', 'H:\\temp\\downloads'])

// STDOUT
var stdOut = result.stdout.toString();
console.log(stdOut)

// STDERR
var stdErr =  result.stderr.toString();

if(stdErr === '') {
    console.log('Successfully set environment variable')
} else {
    console.log(`ERROR: ${stderr}`)
}
```

#### step 2

Open console window as an administrator and type the below commands.

> otherwise »
>
> ERROR: Access to the registry path is denied.

- `cd D:\Codes\JS`
- `node setEnv.js`

Now, have a look at the below images, in my case.

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

#### References

[Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

[SETX command: error: Access to the registry path is denied](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a5593733-a7b5-4079-a3ab-a1f9b29532f7/setx-command-error-access-tot-he-registry-path-is-denied?forum=w7itprogeneral)

https://www.codejava.net/java-core/how-to-set-environment-variables-for-java-using-command-line

Answer (score 0):

I use a generic script for mac and windows like this:

```
#!/bin/node

const { exec } = require("child_process");
const currentOs = require("./getOs");

const os = currentOs();

//==========================================================================
function changeMinNodeVersion() {
    console.log("\nChanging yargs min node version...");

    const minNodeVersion = String(process.versions.node).split('.')[0];
    const yargsVariable = `YARGS_MIN_NODE_VERSION=${minNodeVersion}`;
    const command = `${os === 'darwin' ? `export ${yargsVariable}` : `set ${yargsVariable}`}`;

    console.log(`Excecuting ${command}`);
    
    exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`\nFailed to change min node version: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`\nFailed to change min node version: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }

        console.log(`\nVersion changed to ${minNodeVersion}`);
    });
}

//=========================================================================
changeMinNodeVersion();
```

So i just run using:

```
node ./scriptName.js
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `setx` instead of `set`