# How to append values to the PATH environment variable in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, setx

Following the answer suggested in the question -

[Is it possible to permanently set environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519452/is-it-possible-to-permanently-set-environment-variables)

I was able to set new environment variables permanently with the command -

```
spawnSync('setx', ['-m', 'MyDownloads', 'H:\\temp\\downloads'])
```

But now my goal is to append new values to the PATH environment variable.

Is it possible?

Comment: This seems like a question about Windows and the Setx command, not Node, JavaScript, or Electron.

Comment: You are right! Ill fix it

Comment: Are you try to use my answer?

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. admin permission is not the problem in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just get the environment variable and then append to it?

I.e.

```js
const {spawnSync} = require("child_process");
const current_value = process.env.PATH;
const new_path_value = current_value.concat(";", "/some/new/path");

var result = spawnSync('setx', ['-m', 'PATH', new_path_value])

// STDOUT
var stdOut = result.stdout.toString();
console.log(stdOut)

// STDERR
var stdErr =  result.stderr.toString();

if(stdErr === '') {
    console.log('Successfully set environment variable')
} else {
    console.log(`ERROR: ${stderr}`)
}
```

Update "/some/new/path" and run this as admin as the link you provided suggests and it should work.

Comment: Are you able to source the current environment variable from process.env? What happens when you console.log(current_value) and console.log(new_value)?

Comment: It was my bad, your solution was correct! thank you very much

Comment: I needed to change the line ```console.log(`ERROR: ${stderr}`)``` to ```console.log(`ERROR: ${stdErr}`)```

Answer (score 2):

Run your script with the admin permission:

- Open cmd or PowerShell with admin
- Run `node your_script.js`
- To append `PATH` variable, you can set value is : `%PATH%;your_new_value here` (`%PATH%` get old value)

If you run with electron app, you should require admin permission.

Don't forget `setx` run on window

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between appending to an old value  and set a new value?

Comment: @Paz You can add `%PATH%` to get old value and append your new value

Comment: Ok, now I understand.                                                                                      That's was the first thing that I did with Electron.                                                     I know that the  command in windows is setx -m '%path%;NEW_VALUE' but doesn't work with Electron

Comment: @Paz do you run it with admin permission?

Comment: of course.  the admin permission is only required for the "-m", meaning the variable will be system variable and not user variable. that's the easy part. I'm always ending up setting a new value that overrides the old one instead of appending a new value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have rights to modify my registry, and I also would rather not call an OS command such as `setx`.

The following adds an additional component to the Windows PATH.  I then ran Selenium, which uses the new setting.

```
// Display current value of PATH
const current_value = process.env.PATH;
console.log("PREV VALUE:")
console.log(current_value)

// Add the additional entry
const addl_entry = String.raw`\my\new\path\component`
process.env["PATH"] = addl_entry + ";" + current_value

// Display the new value
console.log("NEW VALUE:")
console.log(process.env.PATH)
```