# Jsdom: how to open a browser with data pulled with 'jsdom'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I want to start using 'jsdom' package
jsdom: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

I saw the following code snippet in the documentation:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
jsdom.env("http://nodejs.org/dist/", [
        'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
    ],
    function(errors, window) {
        console.log(window);
        // I want to open a browser window that will show the content of window
    }
);
```

As you can see, I can use 'jsdom' to pull the data from the website " http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js". Now, I want to take the data I have in 'window' variable, make some manipulations on it and then open a browser and show the manipulated data.

I know that 'open' package can help me open a browser, but I have to give it a URL as an argument. It cannot process 'window' object. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve in long run. I assume that you run node.js on the client machine with a browser installed. If that is true then I would save contents of DOM to a file by using FS and then open a browser with parameters to load that html file.

To get contents you should be able to simply run jquery method:

```
var html = $("html").html();
```

How to use FS:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/path/file.html", html)
```

To open a file in browser you can install [opn](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn) and run it

```
const opn = require('opn');
opn ('file:///path/file.html')
```

Without opn you can run browser binary with a command like in answers to this question: [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)