# How to execute git commands from node using standard terminal commands

Tags: node.js, git, bash

I am trying to merge branches into a main branch programmatically, using a node script. The first thing I tried was from [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js), which worked fine for executing terminal commands. But I encountered difficulties with changing the working directory. I wanted to change the working directory to the git repository, then run git commands from there. Executing `cd ~/repo` or `cd /home/me/repo` did not change the working directory at all and I could not find any way to change it other than using `cd`.

I then tried executing the git commands from the script's directory but pointed at my repo. I tried `git --git-dir` and `git --work-tree` but neither of those commands worked. The error was the same: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` I'm guessing this is because the directory where the script is running from is not a git repo.

So, I either want to send git commands to a directory other than the one I am running the script from, or I want a way to change the script's working directory. Preferably the latter. My full code and output is below:

```
import JiraData from './jiradata';
const jiraData = new JiraData();
const { exec } = require('child_process');

(async function () {
    const cards = await jiraData.getCardsInTest();
    let commands = ['cd /home/me/repo', 'pwd'];
    let proceeding = true;
    // for (const card of cards) {
    //     commands.push(`git merge origin/${card} --commit --no-edit`);
    // }

    for (const command of commands) {
        if (proceeding) {
            console.log(`Executing command "${command}"`);
            exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (err) {
                    proceeding = false;
                    console.log(stderr);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(stdout);
            })
        }
    }
})();
```

Output:

```
> ci@1.0.0 start /home/me/CI
> babel-node index.js --presets es2015,stage-2

Executing command "cd /home/me/repo"
Executing command "pwd"
/home/me/CI
```

Comment: Try `git --git-dir=/home/me/repo/.git --work-tree=/home/me/repo merge foo`. Don't use `~` to replace `/home/me` in the path.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're doing this as a child process, rather than using the npm git package?  It's about a million times easier when using that...   https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodegit

Answer (score 1):

Try instead with:

```
git -C /path/to/git/repo your_git_command
```

That will execute the git command in the context of your git repo  `/path/to/git/repo`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I did already find a solution for this case, but it might be worth simplifying it to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this problem by using ShellJS. ShellJS has a method `.cd()` which changes the directory and seems to stick.