# Run .vbs script with node

Tags: node.js, vbscript

I am trying to find out how I can run a `.vbs` file from a node application.

The script does it's own thing and my node application doesn't need any info back except maybe when the script is finished running.

When I find a way to do this I will then look at passing parameters to the script, but for now I just need to know how I can run the script.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `child_process.spawnSync(command[, args][, options])`. See [a](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_synchronous_process_creation), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35586247/603855). Demo:

Given:

```
|..
+---vbs
|       slave.vbs
|
\---nodejs
        master.js
```

slave.vbs:

```
Option Explicit

Dim a : a = "no arg"
If 0 < WScript.Arguments.Count Then a = WScript.Arguments(0) 
Dim o : o = Array("", WScript.ScriptName, a, Time())
o(0) = "MsgBox"
MsgBox Join(o, "|")
o(0) = "StdOut"
WScript.Stdout.WriteLine Join(o, "|")
o(0) = "StdErr" 
WScript.Stderr.WriteLine Join(o, "|")
WScript.Quit 3
```

master.js:

```
'use strict';

const
    spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawnSync,
    vbs = spawn( 'cscript.exe', [ '../vbs/slave.vbs', 'one' ] );

console.log( `stderr: ${vbs.stderr.toString()}` );
console.log( `stdout: ${vbs.stdout.toString()}` );
console.log( `status: ${vbs.status}` );
```

output:

```
node master.js

(MessageBox)

stderr: StdErr|slave.vbs|one|14:09:39

stdout: StdOut|slave.vbs|one|14:09:39

status: 3
```