# Call VBScript from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vba, vbscript, activexobject

To answer a request from the client, Node.js needs to export charts from Excel files in images into a repository.
I chose to use a VBA Macro because I don't think I have other solutions.
The VBA code is working properly (when I call it manually) but I wish I could connect it with Node.js events. 
VBScript allows me to call a VBA Macro in my script.vbs file :

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
CallVBA

Sub CallVBA() 

   Dim ApplicationExcel 
   Dim ClasseurExcel 

   Set ApplicationExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
   Set ClasseurExcel = ApplicationExcel.Workbooks.Open("H:/macrosVBA.xlsm") 

   ApplicationExcel.Visible = False       
   ApplicationExcel.Run "ChartUpload" 
   ApplicationExcel.Quit 

   Set ClasseurExcel = Nothing 
   Set ApplicationExcel = Nothing 

End Sub
```

My problem now is to run the VBScript in the JavaScript file :

```js
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
objShell.run('H:/script.vbs');
```

I get the error :

```
ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined
```

Adding [win32ole](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32ole) and [winax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winax) doesn't change anything, they don't seem to work anymore.
I'm looking for your help to have another solution or to fix my error with ActiveXObject.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Delete `On Error Resume Next` and `CallVBA`.

Comment: Hello, I didn't test the .vbs file yet because the main problem is calling it from the .js file. Thank you anyway for the correction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run .vbs script with node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218117/run-vbs-script-with-node)

Comment: I tried the program and it works perfectly. However when I apply it to my project with the previous vbs code (without "On Error Resume Next" and "Call VBA") Nothing happens...

Comment: If you remove `CallVBA` then it just defines a sub, but never executes it.

Answer (score 3):

Your Node.js is probably 64bit, whilst your Office/Excel is probably the 32bit version.

You need to run the 32bit VBScript interpreter in order to access the 32bit `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const bat = spawn("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\wscript.exe", ["H:\\script.vbs"]);
```