# Can I put a variable for a filename in the scripts property of package.json

Tags: node.js, package.json, npm-scripts

I would like to do something like this without specifying the filename:

```
"scripts": {
  "test <any_file.js>": "*actual command* <any_file.js>"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually want to do is reading an argument. You can use `process.argv` for that. More about the global node variable `process` to be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html).

When your script tag looks something like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "my-command": "my-script.js"
}
```

When your script file looks something like this:

```
console.log( process.argv );
```

Then all is left to do is run your command with `npm` or `yarn`.

```
npm run my-command <your-argument e.g. file.js>
```

If you want to pass it to another command, you can call that command with a `require( 'child_process' ).exec`. A good example about that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js).

Comment: I'm not actually going to perform testing. Sorry, I just couldn't think of a generic command. Something like `do_something <any_file.js>`?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer :) hope that makes it more clear