# How to pass dynamic file name in npm run command

Tags: npm, command-line

I want to npm run a command to generate a dynamic output file from the file name I pass in the command line. But I am not able to generate that from the below command

In my package.json in the script I have added the command:

```
scripts:{
"gen-out":"some_cmd src/app/parser/$npm_config_filene.st -o src/app/parser/$npm_config_filene.j"
}
```

and after running

```
npm run gen-out --filene=myfile
```

it produces a file with the name $npm_config_filene.js instead of myfile.js

could anyone help, please?

Comment: You're probably running this command on Windows, in which case npm utilizes `cmd` as the default shell for running  npm scripts. Variables in `cmd` are referenced using the `%...%` notation (unlike `sh` on _*nix_ which utilizes the dollar (`$`) prefix). If you are on Windows try encasing the `npm_config_filene` variable in your npm script with `%...%`. For example: `"gen-out":"some_cmd src/app/parser/%npm_config_filene%.st -o src/app/parser/%npm_config_filene%.js"`

Comment: thanks it is working

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606901/can-i-put-a-variable-for-a-filename-in-the-scripts-property-of-package-json answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for windows platform use this format:

```
scripts:{
"gen-out":"some_cmd src/app/parser/%npm_config_filene%.st -o src/app/parser/%npm_config_filene%.j"
}

npm run gen-out --filene=myfile
```