# How to query a directory tree without loading them in memory

Tags: node.js, filesystems, querying

I have a root directory, for example **events**.

Every event is a directory containing files, and there are millions of events.

Directories in the **events** directory:

```
...
2018-01-17-18:40:51.151343-1bb809
2018-01-17-20:55:22.627688-26ada5
2018-01-17-20:55:27.919532-8243cd
2018-01-17-20:56:30.743072-94e913
2018-01-17-20:57:39.824845-64ccb7
...
```

What I am trying to do is:

- Load the directories one by one, instead of doing it in one call e.g. **fs.readDir**
- As the directory names are timestamped, I want to be able to query them with

e.g.

```
{ time: 
    $gte: t1
    $lte: t2
}
```

How would I do this query, with performance, without reading all the directories in memory at once?

I am using NodeJs 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure [node.js File System functions](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/fs.html) you cannot do it.

[fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) exist but it will return all the names at once.

---

**What you can do**

Execute a command line using node.js :

So you can do `find -regex "Here the regexp to match your dates"`

---

*Example from stack* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js) *by @hexacyanide* :

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

async function ls() {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('ls');
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.log('stderr:', stderr);
}

ls();
```