# run npm start in Js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run 'npm start' from a file : test.js . I get :

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { npm start
                                                              ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The content of test.js :

```
npm start
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to avoid starting my node server with npm start directly in the shell and start it with:

```
node test.js
```

And programmatically restart my node server at three differents hours a day.

I'm not  node expert. Can anyone help me or give me ideas to achieve this ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a package.json file? if not then run `npm init` and make one.After that use `npm start`

Comment: As your primary target require running system command from Node.js, you may try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js

Comment: @ Mohhamad Hasham yes i have a package.json file

Comment: Id like a valid answer to this not just using npm, please?
I need to run a profiler on many unit tests, but within IntelliJ, you can't run a profiler against an npm script, you have to run it against an executed file in node.

Answer (score 1):

`npm start` is not a valid javascript code rather it is a command meant to be used from the terminal. To do scheduled restarts you can use modules like [`pm2`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/).