# Get process RAM variable into JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, c, memory, ram

i want to import ram variables of a specific process into javascript.

it's quite simple to get the values using C:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *ptr = (char *)0x12345678; 
    printf("%c\n", *ptr); 
    return 0;
}
```

but how do i get these values into a .js file? 
is there any workaround, any tool to achieve this?

Comment: Since the runtime is going to be node.js, not a browser, just call your c program from node.js.

Comment: i can just a call a c program in node.js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js

Comment: @tipsfedora [yes](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_synchronous_process_creation)

Comment: If you want the incredibly convoluted method, you can compile your C program as a node plugin using `node-gyp`.