# execute linux commands from localhost website

Tags: node.js, linux

I was wondering if it is possible to execute linux commands from a localhosted webpage to a local linux server and get the output send back to the webpage.
If so, how would I be able to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Comment: What is the back-end coding language ? Php, java, JavaScript, ... ?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What are you trying to execute? Lot depends on the command you are trying to execute and the server.

Comment: I am trying to execute aircrack-ng commands, I am trying to make a web gui for a schoolproject to use Aircrack-ng commands used for deauthentication from local machines. the (server) is at this point default kali linux but that can change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In [Node](https://nodejs.org) (which I assume you're using), you can asynchronously call to the shell using the provided [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) command. `exec()` provides a callback which provides `Streams` for stdout and stderr. These can be piped to your response:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

// Or whatever function runs when responding to requests
app.use(function(req, res) => {
    // Pipe the output of the command to 
    exec("<command>", (err, stdout, stderr) => stderr.pipe(res))
})
```