# Fetch execute local bash script through URL

Tags: javascript, bash, fetch-api

I'm wondering how do i convert a curl command to execute a bash script with associating input vars by utilising fetch?

The following works perfectly through the console.

```
  curl -s http://localhost:3001/ident.sh | bash /dev/stdin x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57 2 1019489767657645
```

But then whenever I try to call it using fetch and even without the script arguments:

```
  fetch("http://localhost:3001/ident.sh")
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((data) => {

      console.log(data)

  })
```

OR

```
  fetch("http://localhost:3001/ident.sh", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json' }
  })
  .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
  .then((data) => {

      console.log(data)

  })
```

Which just results in:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Why are you calling `resp.json()`? It's not JSON, it's just plain text that contains a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

`indent.sh` is not returning JSON, it's returning plain text that contains a shell script. If you want to see it, use `resp.text()`, not `resp.json()`.

This won't execute the script. See [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js) for how to execute a command from Node.js.

Comment: Thanks, facing some lovely problems on that end is the only problemo. Cheers for pointing me in the right direction regardless.