# How to create a web application that uses buttons to execute shell scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, shell, web

I have several shell scripts and I would like to execute them by clicking on a button in the client side. How can I manage to do this?

Comment: What have you already done ? Where are you stuck ? Please improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tagged this [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) and [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) so:

1. Create an HTTP server with Node. You can use [Express](https://expressjs.com/) for this.
2. Create a post [route](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) that will run the shell script
3. Use a [child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js) to run that shell script
4. Attach [an event handler](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_12) to your button
5. Have the event handler make an [HTTP POST request](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to your server