# Running npm functs from js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have quite an unusual question.

I don't mean make

> script/test.js

, and then in package

> "node scripts/test.js"

Instead, I want to somehow run function npm list from my test.js file

As in

> let list = npm list

, and i have no idea how to do it, is it even possible? And if so, how? I would also like to save it as string or object. any can work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, here is the code:

```js
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

var list = execSync('yarn list', { encoding: 'utf-8' });
console.log(list);
```

Comment: any way i could save the output as a string or object, or anything else?

Comment: In `callback` function you get the output as a string in `list` argument

Comment: I have updated answer to use simpler code, using execSync