# How to create button to run exe file use node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

im trying to make a desktop gui used node.js to execute my program ,i want to know if there have anyway to create a click button to execute pe(exe) file use node.js and html? (my english not really good hope you can understand :)

Comment: Please clarify. You want something in a browser to run a native executable? If so, this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20643470/1531971

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following sample code :

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('cat *.js missing_file | wc -l', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

And read here carefully :
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html