# How to execute python code(.py file) in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-2.7, protractor

i have to execute python code in protractor to compare two word files. Python code is working fine. How can i execute that python file in javascript file ?

Comment: Could you provide some more information, i.e. source code, things you've already tried, etc. Have you looked at similar questions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell

It provides you a way to call python files from node

Comment: var exec = require('child_process').exec;
            var cmd = 'C:/Python27/Scripts/readDoc.py';

            exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
                // command output is in stdout
            });        this code is working for me ... Thanks