# How to run a .bat file on a node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, server, reboot

I was wondering if you can perform an automatic restart of a server made with node. My idea was to run a .bat file via node that rebooted the server.
It's possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally its possible to reboot a server with batch by calling shutdown.exe

You can execute any file with nodejs. NodeJS documentation is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exec` as follows

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('shutdown -s -t 0') ; // change command according to your system
```

check this question for more details on exec

[Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)