# How to get the output via the VSCode terminal API as string?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VSCode has a [Windows API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window) that allows interaction with the terminal.

For example, you can send the Linux command `pwd`  & the command output may be `/usr/home/userName`

I have tried writing the output to disk & then reading it later by using something like  `pwd > directory.txt`;

```js
terminal.sendText(`pwd > directory.txt`);
```

This seems to work, but I was wondering if there was something more elegant.

```js
//Create a new terminal
let terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal(`Name of terminal`, 'C:\path\to\terminal\shell\shell.exe');

// send command to newly created terminal
terminal.sendText(`pwd`);
```

I know for sure the code above works because  I can write the outputs to a file using;

```
terminal.sendText(`pwd > directory.txt`);
```

So the question is, how do I get the outputs of `terminal.sendText()` as a string without having to first write them to disk?

Comment: If you don't need to show the command being run in a UI terminal, you can just use Node's exec / spawn APIs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js/20643568

Comment: I have tried this with the node-cmd package & it doesn't seem to be working on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Answer (score -1, accepted):

vscode also provides an event to listen to any data being written to the terminal, use the following code to listen to the terminal write :

```sh
vscode.window.onDidWriteTerminalData((e) => {console.log(e.data)})
```

but it'll listen for all the writes, so you'll have to put in some conditonals to prevent reading every keystroke on the terminal, maybe you can read only when e.data == \n or other conditions.

Comment: This was only a proposed API and will never be released, so this is no longer a solution.