# How to run a command using javascript in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have an application which needs to run with the following command:
be-engine.exe -u producer -c D:\Workspace\V114_new\KinesisChannel\kinesis.cdd D:\Workspace\V114_new\KinesisChannel.ear -n logs002

Here i need to navigate to the bin director of the installed application and the  run the be-engine.exe passing other file paths as well in the command on windows.

I want to automate this using protractor so that on start the above commands run automatically and engine gets started. 
Is there a way to do this in protractor using javascript.

Comment: take a look at `grunt task runner`

Comment: You can do this using bat file, mention all of your commands in the .bat file and execute it. This will invoke the other commands as well. I would not recommend to use the protractor for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS has exec method for this:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('be-engine.exe -u producer -c D:\Workspace\V114_new\KinesisChannel\kinesis.cdd D:\Workspace\V114_new\KinesisChannel.ear -n logs002', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Check also this answer: [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)