# Change system / OS time with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, systemtime

Is there a way / library that can change the system time? In my case I need to update the time of a linux machine (Debian). I know there is a way to set the time with a shell command, what I am asking is if there is an abstraction library or another way?

Comment: The Unix system call to do this is `settimeofday`. See if you can find a library that provides a way to call it. I did a couple of google searches and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple if you use your machine's [date](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) command. However, to do this, you'll need to call the system command from your NodeJS script. That is possible with NodeJS's `exec` command. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20643568/1913185). It's basically a way to call system function from inside your NodeJS code. It runs asyncronous, so it requires a callback that has NodeJS `error`, `stdout`, and `stderror`.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const timestamp = '20190927 10:00:00';

exec(`/bin/date --set="${timestamp}"`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err || stderr) {
    console.error(err);
    console.log(stderr);
  } else {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(`Successfully set the system's datetime to ${stdout}`);
  }
}));
```

Likely you won't have a `$PATH` available. Therefore, you'll need to specify the exact path to date. You can find that by running `which date` in a terminal and copying the output into the `exac` statement. For my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, it's located in `/bin/date`.

Comment: This has an extra `)` on the end. Also this method does not seem to work in at least some Docker containers. It yields an error: `/bin/date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted`