# How to run a CLI command from NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I need to write a terminal command like the following within my NodeJS application to copy a S3 file:

```
aws s3 cp s3://path-to-s3-fle local-file
```

Is there a way to do that from within the Node/JavaScript code? Any modules/dependencies that let you easily achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js

Comment: Yes it does, thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js duplicated ^^

Answer (score 4):

See [child_process.exec](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

```js
const {exec} = require('child_process');
exec('aws s3 cp s3://path-to-s3-fle local-file');
```