# How to run sh script from node.js project?

Tags: node.js, sh, child-process, forever

My sh script suddenly closes. I'm trying to control sh process by another script.
Nohup doesn't help me so I decided to use my Node.js working on forever. So I have found child_process lib but doesn't know how to run sh script on it.

Comment: Could you add the code that you tried already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Comment: @Titulum my code doesn't different from the code in the links below.

I just can't find a code with link to specific .sh file. So Im not sure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment under your question I assume what you want is this:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process')

exec('path/to/your/specific/file.sh', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    // do whatever you want
});
```

The path can be relative or absolute and the file must be executable.

Another way would be to explicitly call `sh`.

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process')

exec('sh path/to/your/specific/file.sh', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    // do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: ty. I already found a solution (same code but using 'shelljs' lib). I just use `exec('./file.sh'...` without sh prefix. Thats works for me