# Configure Babel to include sibling modules referenced by alias into compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, monorepo, multi-project

I have the following file structure:

```
application1
|pacakge.json
|src
||file1.ts
widget-lib
|package.json
|src
||file2.ts
||index.ts
```

`.\widget-lib\src\index.ts` bundles and reexports everything in `widget-lib` package.

```
export * from '.\file2'
```

`.\application1\src\file1.ts` and other files refence `widget-lib` by alias

```
import { foo } from 'widget-lib';
```

I'm compiling `.\application1\src\` with Babel into `.\application1\build-test\`, how do I instruct Babel to also include `widget-lib` into this particular compilation? My goal is to produce a folder with all JS files needed to debug unit tests in modern node with `esm` package - just strip down TS types and put resulting JS files into proper place, like this:

```
application1
|build-test
||application1
|||src
||||file1.js
||widget-lib
|||src
||||index.js
||||file2.js
```

I'm using `https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver` to rewrite alias paths like 'widget-lib' to expected relative paths, I just need to instruct babel to also include the actual files from `widget-lib` into `.\build-test\widget-lib` folder. I tried passing both `.\application1\src` and `.\widget-lib\src` together to Babel, but than it outputs content of both `.\src` folders into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running several babel process in parallel, spawning them with a node script as described here [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js/20643568#20643568) and using the script to analyze their output and emit additional information.