# In Babel, can I compile several (source directory -> out directory) pairs in one command?

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, babeljs, aggregation

I'm setting-up VSCode to use Babel in preLaunchTask. I need to compile several source directories, each with its own out-dir, in --watch mode. I can do this with several Babel processes, but it looks like VSCode has a problem with having more then 1 background task as preLaunchTask. Can I somehow configure Babel to compile several in-out directory pairs in one command? Or maybe combine them into single shell command aggregating output of several sub-processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running several babel process in parallel, spawning them with a node script as described here [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js/20643568#20643568) . In the script, I pipe-through their output, and I also scan it, to emit additional marker message for VSCode once initial compilation has been finished for each.