# How can i run a shell command with nodejs without using child_process?

Tags: node.js

I specifically need to run a command with nodejs, but I cannot use `child_process.spawn()`

Is there a way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Comment: The answers in that post all seem to use child_process.spawn() still. I know this request is a a bit strange..

Comment: There are a lot of mentions about `npm` packages that handle `shell` commands.

Comment: And why exactly you cannot use `child_process`? @zhulien Those packages usually just wrap that internal module, adding some syntax sugar.

Comment: Im wrapping node within an iOS project, and iOS doesn't allow to use .spawn()

Comment: @raina77ow Yes, but they're mostly using `child_process.exec()`. I am still not sure if `child_process` or `child_process.spawn()` is the problem here.

Comment: The reason you cant use spawn is because iOS prohibits it.  You will not get around this

Comment: Yeah I’m looking for an alternative way which doesn’t use spawn due the the iOS permissions

Comment: What iOS SDK are you using with node for this?  Some additional tags might help get you more focused responses.