# How to access terminal in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, node-modules

I want to build a nodejs application which will do some automatic work for me . But I want to know if I can execute terminal commands in nodejs . Is there any module which will be helpful to access command line interface ? Suppose I want to run this command `code .` or `ifconfig` or `cd`. So how can I do this from nodejs application ?
I know I can run nodejs from my terminal But I want to access terminal and do whatever I want .like installing other softwares from terminal Like executing 'apt install package-name'

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process

Comment: duplicate of [execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is a portable method of running system specific functionality. Thankfully, nodejs has a module to do this called the [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module. For more specific information you can glance at the linked documentation, but a basic example goes like this:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

// Here we make the call making sure to list the command first and the arguments as the next parameter in a list
const diff = spawn('diff', ["texta.txt", "textb.txt"])

// We can also log the output of this function with
diff.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

// or we can log the exit code with
diff.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```