# Execute sql file using node js command

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a script to create a database for a project I'm working on. In this project don't have been using any ORM, just plain text for the query creation, using a **pg-node** module to do this. I would know if it's possible to execute all `SQL` for the database transactions. For example:

`db_create.sql`, this script has all tables to create. How to run a command like

`npm run serve`, `npm run test`, or whatever other to start an automatic process, in this case, to create a DB or any other database process I will wish.

Comment: If I understood correctly what you need, then try to read these articles. [Executing Shell Commands](https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/) and [Executing Shell Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js) It works the same for windows.