# Is it possible to display .asf video format in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am currently working on a website in which I want to show some videos. My problem is that the video format will be .asf format if I try .asf format nothing is shown in the webpage but if I use mp4 its working correctly. Can anyone suggests me how can I show .asf format and even I have to convert that .asf format to some other format like mp4 what will be the good library to do it??

Comment: If you need to convert videos [Handbrake is a good open-source utility](https://handbrake.fr/).

Comment: Actually I meant converting through backends(like in nodejs) not with some software..

Comment: Why make your life harder? Just get all the videos and batch convert them.

Comment: Companies requirement not my own website..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert .asf to .mp4 using software like [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/). If you want to convert the videos on the frontend there are JavaScript implementations that enable you to use ffmpeg in the browser like [ffmpeg.js](https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js/)

You use ffmpeg.js like you would use the commandline version. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i test1.asf -c:v libx264 -strict -2 test1.mp4
```

This would be done in ffmpeg.js with

```
const result = ffmpeg({
  MEMFS: [{name: "test.webm", data: testData}],
  arguments: ["-i", "test1.asf", "-c:v", "libx264", "-strict", "-2" , "test1.mp4"],
});
```

I copied those arguments from another example. You might want to change or add arguments to get better video quality.

There is also [ffmpeg for node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg) which might suit your case better. But in the backend you can also run the normal ffmpeg via [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20643470/8613630).

Comment: For the frontend do i need to have the normal ffmpeg library installed?

Comment: for the frontend you can either co with https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js/ or https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm