# How to convert DER to PEM using Nodejs

Tags: pem, pki, der

I want to convert DER content to PEM format using Nodejs.

I couldn't find any suitable library or logic. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you find bindings to OpenSSL  (or can make a shell/system call to run it) you can do a search on conversions using that.

Comment: Why not [call the command](https://www.poftut.com/convert-der-pem-pem-der-certificate-format-openssl/) with [node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js) directly?

Answer (score 0):

This is (now?) built directly into the Node.js crypto library.

```
const crypto = require( 'crypto' );
```

You can import a private key in DER format:

```
const key = crypto.createPrivateKey( { key: privkeyInDerFormat, format: 'der', type: 'pkcs8' } );
```

And then export it in PEM format:

```
const privkeyInPemFormat = key.export( { format: 'pem', type: 'pkcs8' } );
```

Done! :)