# How do I make a NodeJS Script to do something like os.system on Python?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Python Script, I can simply make it like this:

```
import os
import asyncio

async def do_something():
    os.system("pip list")
    
asyncio.run(do_something())
```

But what about on JavaScript/NodeJS? I see one module named 'os' too in there, but how do I use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `child_process` library to run bash commands. Example below.

```js
import { exec } from "child_process";


exec("pip list", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(stdout);
})
```