# Deprecated Github Action ::set-output name=key::value in javascript

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions, workflow

I'm working on a GitHub Actions workflow using Node.js, and I need to set an output value to be used in subsequent steps. I am getting deprecated warning for for the line.

```
process.stdout.write(`::set-output name=my-key::'${value}'`);
```

Action.yml:

```
name: Test New Output
description: 'Task to test new output'



runs:
  using: 'node16'
  main: 'test-output.js'
```

Full node.js is below

```js
const fs = require('fs');


async function run() {
  try {
    // Calculate the value for 'blocks'
    const blocks = "some value";
    process.stdout.write(`::set-output name=my-key::'${blocks}'`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

run();
```

Can anybody suggest what is the alternative for this deprecated usage.

Comment: See [`core.setOutput`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#using-workflow-commands-to-access-toolkit-functions).

Comment: I am getting errors when tried to import actions/core.

Comment: Are you following https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action?

Comment: This is for a private project. So I can't create a public repo for custom action. 
My custom action works fine now. I am trying to address the warning about the usage of deprecated 'set-output'

Comment: See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter and you need to run it modify it for invocation from your script.

Comment: @Azeem I didn't get it. Could you please point to an example.

Comment: Currently, you're writing to stdout but with the new syntax of `GITHUB_OUTPUT`, you have to run it as a command and redirect its output to `GITHUB_OUTPUT`. You may use `child_process` for this if you don't want to use `core.setOutput`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js. So, in your case, the command would be `echo "key=value" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"` and you'll be invoking it with `child_process`'s `exec` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Azeem.
For anyone looking for a quick solution.

The .js file will look like this.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const outputValue = 'Your output value'; // Replace this with your actual output value

exec(`echo "MY_OUTPUT_NAME=${outputValue}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`);
```