# Is there any way to call an executable file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am currently make a web-based system for my company (have to be Node.js). This project is to replace an old Winforms app. There are a lot of stand-alone executable files from the old apps that do calculations and update data to database.

One of the requirement for the new system is to be able to re-use these files because the manager doesn't want to spend time to rewrite these into the new system.

The system have 2 Node.js project, a front-end with React for webpages, and a back-end as API for handle calculation and DB. With the back-end project, is it possible to call the executable files placed on server local drive?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643470/execute-a-command-line-binary-with-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the server can use any of the functions in the [child_process module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) such as `spawn()` or `exec()` to run other executables on the server.  Your server can either just run them and let them do their thing or they can run and the server can capture output from them and feed that back to the client.

You will have to make absolutely sure that this is safe to run these on the server and that arguments coming from the client that might be sent to these apps do not create a security risk on the server.

Comment: Thanks. Do these executable files have to be in the project folder, or can they be place anywhere? It would be the best if the back-end can run the files placed on network drive from the file server.

Comment: @N.D.H.Vu - If you go look at that functions in the child_process module, you will see that you can pass a path to the executable so you can run anything that is accessible via a path, is an executable and which you have execution rights to.